# Хранение данных мессенджера в БД

Tags: php, mysql

На этапе создание супер-пупер-самого-лучшего-в-мире-мессенджера возник вопрос. При загрузке страницы необходимо вывести адресную книгу (имена всех юзеров, с которыми велась переписка). Можно пробежать скриптом всю БД (select ... where ) и вывести сгруппированные данные, а можно изначально хранить эти контакты в другой таблице и обновлять динамически. Какой путь избрать?

Comment: Смотря какая БД и смотря как индексы настроены. Взять, к примеру, ваш второй вариант. Получается нужно каждый раз проверять добавлялся один пользователь к другому в контакты или ещё нет. Делать REPLACE, или навесить всё на триггеры. С другой стороны, запрос списка контактов происходит не столь часто, как написание сообщения. 

И, кстати, сдаётся мне, вы что-то скрываете, и для полноценного ответа желательно получить более подробное описание самого мессенджера и принципа его работы.

Comment: @istem, ничего подобного, просто я АБСОЛЮТНО ничего не знаю про принципы этих ваших мессенджеров и т.д. И мне на них глубоко... . Просто знать все это необходимо. Когда доделаю, обязательно кину вам ссылку.))

Comment: @istem, тут же все элементарно - сидит Петя, видит в адресной книге Машу , Катю и Васю. Кликает на Васе - оба-на - вся переписка налицо. Реализация проста. Загвоздка в этой самой реализации адресной книги.

Comment: Будет время, пишите в личку - расскажу про собственную реализацию, может пригодится.

Comment: Не нашел я эту вашу личку.

Comment: @Deus, ну естественно.

Comment: @istem, наверное потому что ее здесь нет.

Comment: Каким образом человек, отсутствующий в моих контактах, может написать мне?

Я так понимаю, что для отправки сообщения надо человека добавить в контакты? Т.е. REPLACE не обязательно делать при каждой же отправке сообщений, если я могу писать только тем, кто у меня уже есть в контактах. Или каким образом у вас все это происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бррр.... У вас какие-то странные дебри... А в чем тут может быть проблема?

Две таблицы: Юзеры и КонтактЛист.

Таблица контакт лист, по хорошему вообще состоит из ИДвладельца, ИДконтакта, Статус. С уникальным ключем по первым двум полям.

ИДвладельца - это то, по чему вы запрашиваете "дайте мне мой контакт лист".

ИДконтакта - это ссылка на таблицу юзеров все тех, кто есть в контакт листе.

Статус... Ну это чтоб иметь возможность делать разрешения добавления (то есть сначала добавляется со статусом 0 - и даем мало инфы, потом, когда вторая сторона разрешила - ставим статус 1 и даем больше инфы).

Естественно, для когда Маша добавляется к Пете, в эту таблицу вставляется две записи, одна для Маши, вторая для Пети. И если Маша удалит Петю, это не значит, что у Пети Маша тоже должна пропасть))

Comment: @SilverIce, отлично. Просто не могу свыкнуться с мыслью, что БД и экономия объема занимаемой памяти - это несовместимые понятия. Если у юзера 129 контактов, то и в таблице только для него одного будет 129 записей... А я постоянно ищу пути с минимальными затратами (в голове моей упорно рулит spectrum с 48 RAM).Я наверное не до конца понимаю сущность БД.

Comment: @Deus. Начинайте отвыкать) Мне тут попадаются промышленные контроллеры с 500Kb RAM, а на "контроллерах" на базе АРМ9 видел даже 1Гб (собственно я видел телефоны с гигом мозгов).